# How to extend a Haskell type instance?

Tags: haskell, ghci

[This](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#a-yes-no-typeclass) excellent tutorial, defines a `YesNo` typeclass and a `YesNo Int` instance as following:

```
class YesNo a where
   yesno :: a -> Bool

instance YesNo Int where
   yesno 0 = False
   yesno _ = True
```

This works fine with an explicit type declaration like:

```
*Main> yesno (0::Int)
False
```

I want to avoid the explicit type declaration and make it work with `Num a` class constraint:

```
instance (Num a) => YesNo a where
   yesno 0 = False
   yesno _ = True
```

But this instance definition does not compile with the error:
`Constraint is no smaller than the instance head`

I understand that `Num` has a larger number of constructors than the `YesNo` class and hence the error. But how do I fix this without setting the `UndecidableInstances` compiler flag?

Comment: `Num` implies `Eq`: `class  (Eq a, Show a) => Num a`

Comment: The constraints `Eq a, Show a` for `Num a` have been dropped since `base-4.5`

Comment: `UndecidableInstances` is fairly harmless. The worst it could happen is that you create a set of instances which get stuck in an infinite loop. Even in this case, as long as the compiler terminates its job, your program will be OK at runtime.

Comment: You say "`Num` has a larger number of constructors [presumably you mean "instances" instead of "constructors"] than the`YesNo` class and hence the error". But this is not a correct characterization of the error -- it is not that the *number of instances* for `Num` is larger, it is that *the type in the instance you are looking for* is not structurally smaller, hence it is not clear that instance search will terminate from syntactic arguments alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As chi already remarked, `-XUndecidableInstances` is not that much of a problem – alright, it's more intrusive than, say, `-XFlexibleInstances`; you should think for a moment whenever this is needed – but it's perfectly *safe*. It will never succeed in compiling code that doesn't work the intended way.

That said, to achieve the goal of allowing `yesno 0` to work on its own, `instance (Num a) -> YesNo a` is *not* the right thing. With that instance in place, it will still be totally ambiguous what concrete type the number `0` is supposed to have (`Num a => a` is *not* a concrete type). Hence the compiler must jump in with *defaulting* and, well, the default `Num` type is `Integer`. Hence, to get this working it's completely sufficient to declare that instance:

```
instance YesNo Integer where
   yesno = (/=0)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer the calculation to be *always* done in `Int`, you can achieve that with an equational constraint:

```
instance (a ~ Int) => YesNo a where
   yesno = (/=0)
```

This one does require `-XUndecidableInstances` though (plus the totally harmless `-XFlexibleInstances` and either of `-XGADTs` or `-XTypeFamilies`, to enable the equational constraint).

None of this makes much sense *anyway*: the point of a type class is to make instances for types whose implementation looks *different*. If you restrict this to number types, which is what you do with these instances, then you might as well stay away from type classes entirely and just define

```
yesno :: (Num n, Eq n) => n -> Bool
yesno = (/=0)
```

In that sense: undecidable instances are a bit of a *code smell*; before writing one make sure you actually *need a class* at all!

Comment: Actually, `FlexibleInstances` can be worse than `UndecidableInstances`! Flexible instances don't always reduce as readily as one might wish.

Comment: Ok... example / link?